# SH Script: Problem with Red Hat Linux Enterprise (Santiago and Tikanga)

Tags: bash, shell, redhat

I have made a script in order to get the free space on partitions like root, var, tmp, opt and usr. But I have 3200 systems which are working fine, and another 1186 systems, mostly RHEL (Tikanga and Santiago), and some CentOS derivations which are working weird. But systems like RHEL (Maipo) are working fine.

Also, I cant connect personally to those servers in order to troubleshoot. I just can run the script remotely.

```
#!/bin/sh

df -h / /var /tmp /opt /usr > /freespace.txt

rootSpace=$(awk 'NR==2 { print $4 }' /freespace.txt)
varSpace=$(awk 'NR==3 { print $4 }' /freespace.txt)
tmpSpace=$(awk 'NR==4 { print $4 }' /freespace.txt)
optSpace=$(awk 'NR==5 { print $4 }' /freespace.txt)
usrSpace=$(awk 'NR==6 { print $4 }' /freespace.txt)

customSpace="root=$rootSpace,var=$varSpace,tmp=$tmpSpace,opt=$optSpace,usr=$usrSpace"
```

- I expect output like **root=890M,var=3.1G,tmp=5.0G,opt=842M,usr=1.4G**
- But I receive outputs like **root=,var=,tmp=28%,opt=,usr=5%**

Why DF its not giving the same outputs in order to sort them with AWK?

Comment: To debug, can you get the content of freespace.txt remotely ?

Comment: can you edit your Q to include the text of you `/freespace.txt` file? (even 1 from a working server and 1 from a not working server?). I bet  you'll find there are significant differences in the layout of information. Rather than user `NR==2` (etc), I would match for specific text, i.e. `/\/root/{print $4}'`. Good luck.

Comment: @CCH Sadly thats the main problem that I have. I can not debug since I dont have full rights and its complicated

Comment: @shellter Tommorow I will come back with a feedback :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest to use `df -hP` if you want to parse df's output.

> `-P`: use the POSIX output format

This keeps all informations in one row, no matter how long the device name is.